# RetURL and SaveURL from Visualforce Page to native Page SF1 N

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a problem about setting the the retURL and SaveURL in a link of a button that I have in my Visualforce page. My Visualforce page load in SF1 and I have an "edit button" which opens the edit sf1 native page of my campaign__c. Once is open the edit page, I change some fields, then, I push save button and it goes back in the Visualforce page ... The strange thing is that it charge my Visualforce page without any changes, and if I try to go back from there, it is reloaded with all the new changes! it seems that the saveURL that I write, it sets in the back button of my Visualforce page and not in the "save button" of Edit native SF1 page.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.CustomCampaign__c.Edit, CustomCampaign__c.Id, ['saveURL'='/apex/DetailCustomCampaign?id='+CustomCampaign__c.Id])}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
```

HAS SOMEONE AN IDEA OF HOW IT CAN DO ??